# How to write query on kibana UI search bar to get top 6records only based on filter

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to fetch top 6 results only based on my condition.
How can we write a query on search bar.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe easiest way of doing it to write in the search field **app_name: "xyz"**. Then hover over the left pane, on the fields which you can filter.

[image]

You can change the number of top values by going to the left window, Stack Management -> Kibana -> Advanced Settings -> The top N most popular fields to show

If you click on the plus sign on the top X results on left pane, it filters automatically.

Alternatively you can make query in DEVTOOLS in Kibana with this example query.

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "app_name": "xyz"
    }
  },
  "size": 6
}
```

and it fetched 6 top hits.

Comment: Ok. But I want to use this query for my grafana dashboard. I want to show only top 6 records on grafana

Comment: I edited my comment above. I am not sure if Kibana Query Language is strong enough to fetch this information but I used DEVTOOLS integrated on Kibana.